# How to compile code so that JSON is seperate from the main.js with webpack?

Tags: webpack

I have a bunch of React files that I want to be compiled into a main.js file. I also have one JSON file, which my main file uses to read information. Right now, when I compile it, everything is being compiled into main.js, but I want the JSON to be separate from it and still be able to read it.

This is how I require my JSON:

```js
const outline = require('./outlineQuestions.json');
```

I have already tried the following approaches:

- https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin

  - It copies the JSON over, but it is still being bundled into the main.js
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename

  - here it tells me how I could handle more than one output, but the problem lies it is talking about JS files only.
- https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

  - this was suggested, but it's deprecated for Webpack 5, instead Asset Modules is recommended
- https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

  - Which worked out, it did *not* bundle it into the main.js, but now it doesn't work anymore in production.

I want to give both of those files to my client, so they can edit the JSON file, so they can add or change information. With Asset Modules the JSON file wasn't bundled into the main.js, which is great. But now Main.js is not working, because it can't read the JSON.

I am using Webpack 5. This problem occurs with Production, *not* in Development.
Here is my `webpack.prod.js`.

```js
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    filename: 'applicationGeneratorOutputOnly.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: './',
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(), new TerserPlugin()],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'applicationLetter.css' }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.css$/i,
      //   type: 'asset/resource',
      //   generator: {
      //     filename: '[name].css',
      //   },
      // },
      // {
      //   test: /\.json$/i,
      //   type: 'asset/resource',
      //   generator: {
      //     filename: '[name].json',
      //   },
      // },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.resolve(
            __dirname,
            'src',
            'applicationQuestions.json'
          ),
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

is your console erroring out any messages? I had the same problem, but as soon as updated some dependencies from errors tips coming from the console the application was able to find the json files.

Comment: Hey, I don't remember what happened 10 months ago anymore, but I think i never found a solution to it and just did it manually.